# Why does my div dont go fullscreen?

Tags: jquery

why does my button expand down in height and not equally to the top and bottom so it would cover the fullscreen?

And the Border lines should stop at the size of the parent div... I cant make it work.. do you have any ideas? (to make the doggies disappear :DD)

```js
var main = function(){
    $('#Music').click(function(){
        $('#soundcloud').animate({
            bottom:'0px'
        },200);

        $('body').animate({
            bottom:'285px'
        }, 200);

    });

    $('#Home').click(function(){
        $('#title').css("-webkit-text-fill-color", "transparent")
        $('.dick').css("background-image", "url(RegenBack.jpg)")
        $('#soundcloud').animate({
            bottom:'-285px'
        },200);

        $('body').animate({
            bottom:'0px'
            },200);
    });

    $('#button').mouseup(function () {
        var d = {};
        $('#button').removeClass('shadow')
        $('#button').find('p').removeClass('textshadow')
        $('#button').find('p').css("visibility", "hidden")
        $('#button').css("z-index", "999")
        $('#button').removeClass('shadow')
        $('#button').animate({
            width: '100%'
        },500,function() {
            $('#button').animate({
                height: '100%'
            }, 500);
        });

    });



    $('#button').mousedown(function() {
        $('#button').find('p').addClass('textshadow')
        $('#button').addClass('shadow')

    });



};

$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
.menu{
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#button p{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: -15px;
    font-size: 100px;
    font-family: mySecondFont;
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
}
#button{
    background: url(https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000532546226/dbe5f0727b69487016ffd67a6689e75a.jpeg) fixed;
    width: 622px;
    height: 148px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border-color: white black black white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -3px -3px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

.textshadow{
    background-color: #000000;
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
}

.shadow {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 9px 9px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75).inset -2px -2px 15px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1) !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 9px 9px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75), inset -2px -2px 15px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1) !important;
    box-shadow: inset 9px 9px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75), inset -2px -2px 15px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1) !important;
}

#soundcloud{
    bottom: -200px;  /* start off behind the scenes */
    height: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

div div div div  p{
    border: 5px solid white;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 70px;
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div div div div p:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    border-color: grey;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: grey;
}

#Music {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 70%;
}

#Home {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 70%;
}

#About {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 70%;
}

#Media {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 70%;
}

.dick {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(http://www.prevention.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/slideshow_display/dog-dogue-de-bordeaux-puppy-410x290.jpg);
}


#title {
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
    cursor: default;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: inherit;
    background: url(Textur1.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    font-family: mySecondFont;
    font-size: 200px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}


div p{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 70px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url(/Fonts/Bask/BaskOldFace.woff);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: mySecondFont;
    src: url(Fonts/Script/ScriptMTBold.woff);
}

body, hmtl{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="de">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Bolle | Music</title>
        <link href="bootstrap-3.3.2-dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="Bolle%20Music.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="dick">
        <div id="button">
            <p>Get Happy</p>
        </div>
            </div>

            <div id="soundcloud"></div>
        <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Ani.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Im thankful for any tips :)
Greetings

Bolle

Answer (score 0):

You have a margin-top property set to 200px on the button. That property stays after the button expands.